# Rails Paperclip S3 Cannot delete uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using Rails 4.2 and Paperclip 4.3.0. Using AWS S3 for my static and uploaded files in production.

I can upload the file and view the uploaded files in my application, but, when i destroy my object model, the uploaded files is not deleted. The log says.

> [AWS S3 403 0.004915 0 retries]
>   head_object(:bucket_name=>"test",:key=>"product_images/data/000/000/014/thumb/aoj_v1.jpg")
>   AWS::S3::Errors::Forbidden AWS::S3::Errors::Forbidden

Here is my bucket policy.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1442210342203",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1442210315335",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::234289374982:root"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1442210338170",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue where I can upload to S3 with Paperclip but not delete, and this only occurs on Heroku (not locally).